# Dot product of vector valued function

Tags: vectors

I know that a dot product $p\cdot q$ measures the projection of parts $p$ on $q$, so that if $p$ and $q$ are orthogonal, $p\cdot  q$ = 0. However, I have been wondering about whether this applies to the dot product of any arbitrary vector valued function ( with vectors as inputs) of $p$ and $q.$ Would, in general, $f(p)\cdot f(q)$ be 0 when $p$ and $q$ are orthogonal? (where $f(p)$ and $f(q)$ are any arbitrary vector valued function with vectors as inputs evaluated at $p$ and $q$)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dot Product Of Vector Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314319/dot-product-of-vector-functions)

Comment: I already know that the dot product of two vector valued functions is a scalar function.However, I am not sure whether that scalar- valued function would be zero when the vectors that the $2$ functions take are orthogonal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, if $p,\,q$ are $n$-dimensional vectors and $A,\,B$ are $n\times n$ matrices then $Ap\cdot Bq=p\cdot(A^TB)q$ depends on $A^TB$. In particular, we could choose $A=I$, then choose $B$ so $Bq\parallel p$, so $Ap\cdot Bq\ne0$ (unless $Bq=0$).

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a constant non-zero function, then $f(p)\cdot f(q)$ is a constant non-zero scalar for any $p$ and $q$, orthogonal or not.

There are many examples that are less extreme. The more interesting question would be what functions preserve the orthogonality property for all pairs of vectors.